# System.Net.WebException while downloading file

Tags: c#, web-services, file, download, httpwebrequest

I have a list of mp3 which I am downloading. After some files are downloaded, not all of them - around 5-7, I get `WebException`. I did a stacktrace and this is the result.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Debug message: The operation has timed out
InnerEx:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at iBlock.Main._InetGetHTMLSearch(String sArtist) in C:\Users\...\Main.cs:line 590
```

My _`InetGetHTMLSearch` looks like this

```
private void _InetGetHTMLSearch(string sArtist)
        {
            aLinks.Clear();
            if (AudioDumpQuery == string.Empty)
            {
                //return string.Empty;
            }
            string[] sStringArray;
            string sResearchURL = "http://www.audiodump.biz/music.html?" + AudioDumpQuery + sArtist.Replace(" ", "+");
            string aRet;
            HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sResearchURL);
            webReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 5.0(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit / 537.75.14(KHTML, like Gecko) Version / 7.0.3 Safari / 7046A194A";
            webReq.Referer = "http://www.audiodump.com/";
            webReq.Timeout = 5000;
            try
            {
                webReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                webReq.Method = "GET";
                using (WebResponse response = webReq.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                        aRet = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        //Console.WriteLine(aRet);
                        string[] aTable = _StringBetween(aRet, "<BR><table", "table><BR>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
                        if (aTable != null)
                        {
                            string[] aInfos = _StringBetween(aTable[0], ". <a href=\"", "<a href=\"");
                            if (aInfos != null)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < aInfos.Length; i++)
                                {

                                    //do some magic here
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //debug
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //debug 2
                        }
                    }
                    response.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Debug message: " + ex.Message + "InnerEx: " + ex.StackTrace);
                aLinks.Clear();
                return;
                //throw exception
            }
        }
```

what this method does is simple. A simple search of the `sArtist` given at `audiodump.com`

I have a timer which runs very fast, every 10ms.

```
private void MainTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _DoDownload(DoubleDimList[i][y], ref mp3ToPlay);
            if (muted) Mute(0);
            if (Downloading)
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Downloading: " + DoubleDimList[i][y];
            }
        }
```

Now this timer handles the download in the background in a Global scope.
The _`DoDownload` methos which basically starts the entire process looks like this

```
private void _DoDownload(string dArtist, ref string dPath)
        {
            if (!Contain && skip <= 3 && !Downloading)
            {
                try
                {
                    _InetGetHTMLSearch(dArtist);
                    if (aLinks.Count < 1)
                    {
                        //skip and return
                        Console.WriteLine("Skipping: " + dArtist);
                        IniWriteValue(_playlists[i], "Track " + y, dArtist + " -iBlockSkip");
                        y++;
                        return;
                    }
                    string path = mp3Path + "\\" + dArtist + ".mp3";
                    if (DownloadOne(aLinks[0], path, false))
                    {
                        hTimmer.Start();
                        Downloading = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Download start error: " + Ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else if (Downloading)
            {
                try {
                    int actualBytes = strm.Read(barr, 0, arrSize);
                    fs.Write(barr, 0, actualBytes);
                    bytesCounter += actualBytes;
                    double percent = 0d;
                    if (fileLength > 0)
                        percent =
                            100.0d * bytesCounter /
                            (preloadedLength + fileLength);
                    label1.Text = Math.Round(percent) + "%";
                    if (Math.Round(percent) >= 100)
                    {
                        string path = mp3Path + "\\" + dArtist + ".mp3";
                        label1.Text = "";
                        dPath = path;
                        aLinks.Clear();
                        hTimmer.Stop();
                        hTimmer.Reset();
                        fs.Flush();
                        fs.Close();
                        lastArtistName = "N/A";
                        Downloading = false;
                        y++;
                        if (y >= DoubleDimList[i].Count)
                        {
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (Math.Round(percent) <= 1)
                    {
                        if (hTimmer.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 3000)
                        {
                            string path = mp3Path + "\\" + dArtist + ".mp3";
                            hTimmer.Stop();
                            hTimmer.Reset();
                            fs.Flush();
                            fs.Close();
                            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                            Contain = false;
                            skip += 1;
                            Downloading = false;
                        }
                    } }
                catch(Exception Ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Downloading error: " + Ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now once the exception is thrown it messes up the entire project. As you see in the last method, if _`InetGetHTMLSearch` doesn't update the search(returns nothing) I am skipping and moving to next search. However the exception will be thrown in every next search. I tried setting new cookies in every search but still didn't work.

Any solutions how to avoid this issue?

P.S. I have to say that if I change the timer's `Interval` to 500ms it will download more mp3 before the exception is thrown but not all of them.

Edit: The issue here is obvious. The request timesout but even if I set it to `Timeout.Infinite` it will hand there forever

Comment: I reckon it's the timer ticking at 500 milliseconds when the request is taking longer, eg at 5000 milliseconds to timeout. Do Async downloading to try and fix it

Comment: Can I do an Async download? I am downloading in a global scope. With a timer. Async can't be done the way I have it. _INetGetHTMLSearch is called once even though _DoDownload which calls it runs every 10ms. So I doubt it is the ticking or the request.

Comment: **Runs every 10ms**.. The exception occurs because `The operation has timed out`

Comment: Well then why it doesn't timeout since the first time but only after some tries? Is it just case of "luck" that the operation doesn't time out before 10ms?
I am simply trying to understand here. I am already changing the project to async download

Comment: I gave it a shot and it is very complicated. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827867/nested-async-download-async-within-async