# Nested Async Download - Async within Async

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, download, async-await

I have some nested async methods calling each other and it is confusing. I am trying to convert a project which downloads the files in an async download.
On the click of the download button this is the method triggered:

```
private async void enableOfflineModeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < _playlists.Count; i++)
            {
                DoubleDimList.Add(new List<String>());
                for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    string sMp3 = IniReadValue(_playlists[i], "Track " + j);
                    DoubleDimList[i].Add(sMp3);
                }
                await Task.Run(() =>  _InetGetHTMLSearchAsyncs(DoubleDimList[i]));              
            }
        }
```

It creates a `2d List` which at the end looks like this `DoubleDimList[3][20]`.
At the end of each `sublist` I am doing an `async` download as you can see. The method looks like this

```
private async Task _InetGetHTMLSearchAsyncs(List<string> urlList)
        {
            foreach (var url in urlList)
            {
                await Task.Run(() => _InetGetHTMLSearchAsync(url));
            }
        }
```

the `_InetGetHTMLSearchAsync` method looks like this and here is where it gets tricky

```
private async Task _InetGetHTMLSearchAsync(string sTitle)
        {
            Runs++;
            if (AudioDumpQuery == string.Empty)
            {
                //return string.Empty;
            }
            string sResearchURL = "http://www.audiodump.biz/music.html?" + AudioDumpQuery + sTitle.Replace(" ", "+");
            try
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.Headers.Add("Referer", @"http://www.audiodump.com/");
                    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla / 5.0(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit / 537.75.14(KHTML, like Gecko) Version / 7.0.3 Safari / 7046A194A");
                    client.DownloadStringCompleted += Client_DownloadStringCompleted;
                    await Task.Run(() => client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(sResearchURL)));

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Debug message: " + ex.Message + "InnerEx: " + ex.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine("Runs: " + Runs);
                return;
            }
        }
```

On `Client_DownloadStringCompleted` there is another `async` method called. Here it is

```
private async void Client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] sStringArray;
            string aRet = e.Result;
            string[] aTable = _StringBetween(aRet, "<BR><table", "table><BR>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            if (aTable != null)
            {
                string[] aInfos = _StringBetween(aTable[0], ". <a href=\"", "<a href=\"");
                if (aInfos != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    {
                        sStringArray = aInfos[i].Split('*');
                        sStringArray[0] = sStringArray[0].Replace("&#39;", "'");
                        aLinks.Add(sStringArray[0]);
                    }
                    await Task.Run(() => DownloadFile(aLinks[FilesDownloaded]));
                }
            }
        }
```

From there, surprise! Another `async` call.

```
private async Task DownloadFile(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.Headers.Add("Referer", @"http://www.audiodump.biz/");
                    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla / 5.0(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit / 537.75.14(KHTML, like Gecko) Version / 7.0.3 Safari / 7046A194A");
                    client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;
                    await Task.Run(() => client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, mp3Path + "\\" + count + ".mp3"));

                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File download error: " + Ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

Now the first part after the creation of the `2d List` is to retrieve the download links of the mp3s. The second part is to download the mp3 as soon as a valid `URL` was provided. It works but in a bizarre way. Instead of downloading the file normally(1st, 2nd, 3rd...), it will download randomly the files(1st, 5th, 8th...).

It is my first go for `async` download and boy, I am already far from my limits.

Where am I messing this up? And the main question, will this ever work the way it is supposed to work?

Comment: There's way too much code here, and yet not enough. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem. In the meantime, I'll point out that using `Task.Run()` to execute `async` methods is generally pointless. Just call the `async` method directly and `await` the returned `Task` object. You can collect a group of `async` calls by representing the returned `Task` as some `IEnumerable<Task>`, and then use `await Task.WhenAll(...)` to wait for the whole collection.

Comment: If you study the existing references for `async`/`await` more carefully and use good idioms, I'll bet most your issues would just go away. All that said, note that if you execute multiple operations asynchronously, it is not surprising at all for them to complete in some order different than in which they are started. That's _why_ you use asynchronous operations; otherwise, you might as well just execute them synchronously one at a time.

Comment: You don't need to wrap your async methods in a Task.Run. It is not needed and it makes your code more difficult to read. You just can await the Task returning Async methods. The reason for the different order of execution is also because you fire the download's in a Task.Run which starts the download. Then the method is returned and the next download is started. The order in which the completed event is fired depends on the request time itself. If you really want to keep the order you should use the DownloadStringTaskAsync instead this returns a task that you can await for the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks pretty good, except for two things:

1. You shouldn't be using `Task.Run`. The primary use case for `Task.Run` is for moving CPU-bound work off a GUI thread so it doesn't block the UI. I have a series on the [proper use of `Task.Run`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) that goes into this in detail.
2. You should use a consistent asynchronous pattern, ideally [TAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx). Your code is currently using TAP everywhere *except* in `_InetGetHTMLSearchAsync`, which is using [EAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx). This is what is causing the odd behavior you're seeing.

A fixed `_InetGetHTMLSearchAsync` would look something like this:

```
private async Task _InetGetHTMLSearchAsync(string sTitle)
{
  Runs++;
  string sResearchURL = "http://www.audiodump.biz/music.html?" + AudioDumpQuery + sTitle.Replace(" ", "+");
  try
  {
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
      client.Headers.Add("Referer", @"http://www.audiodump.com/");
      client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla / 5.0(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit / 537.75.14(KHTML, like Gecko) Version / 7.0.3 Safari / 7046A194A");
      string[] sStringArray;
      string aRet = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(sResearchURL));
      string[] aTable = _StringBetween(aRet, "<BR><table", "table><BR>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
      if (aTable != null)
      {
        string[] aInfos = _StringBetween(aTable[0], ". <a href=\"", "<a href=\"");
        if (aInfos != null)
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
          {
            sStringArray = aInfos[i].Split('*');
            sStringArray[0] = sStringArray[0].Replace("&#39;", "'");
            aLinks.Add(sStringArray[0]);
          }
          await DownloadFile(aLinks[FilesDownloaded]); // Should really be called "DownloadFileAsync"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Debug message: " + ex.Message + "InnerEx: " + ex.StackTrace);
    Console.WriteLine("Runs: " + Runs);
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't using 'Task.Run' before posting here. VS2015 keeps recommending me to use it even though I don't have. That's why I did it. It probably was a glitch of a method. Thank you for the help. I will definitely take a look at the links provided above.

Comment: @JohnP.: I believe the message you're getting is "Consider using the await operator to await not-blocking API calls, or `await Task.Run` to do CPU-bound work on a background thread". And we're not doing CPU-bound work here. You'd only get this message if you're applying async from the "outside in", which is opposite of the more natural approach of making your lowest-level API calls use await first and letting it grow out from there.